# HttpOnly Cookies Not Available in Apex

Tags: apex, httpresponse, cookies

When making an HTTP callout using `HttpRequest`, `Set-Cookie` headers returned with the `HttpOnly` flag are not included in the `HttpResponse`.  This appears to be consistent with RFC 6265:

> The HttpOnly attribute limits the scope of the cookie to HTTP
>      requests.  In particular, the attribute instructs the user agent to
>      omit the cookie when providing access to cookies via "non-HTTP" APIs
>      (such as a web browser API that exposes cookies to scripts).

Is there a way to make use of cookies set with the `HttpOnly` flag in subsequent `HttpRequest` objects?  Support for an opaque cookie jar would be useful so that each time an `HttpRequest` is sent using `Http.send`, the cookies in the jar are sent, and the cookie jar is updated when `Set-Cookie` headers are included in the response.  Something like:

```
CookieJar jar = new CookieJar();
Http callout = new Http();
callout.setCookieJar(jar);
```

This problem has recently broken our integration between Salesforce and GoodData.  I don't know if `HttpOnly` support was added in Winter '14 or if GoodData just started setting the `HttpOnly` flag.

Here's some [sample code](https://github.com/cwarden/apex-httponly-cookie-tests/blob/master/src/classes/RestTestController.cls) to demonstrate the problem.

Any ideas on how to address this problem?

Comment: That sounds broken to me. Apex Code isn't a malicious JavaScript potentially injected into a page (the intent of 6265), it's a controlled scripting language in control of the user/developer.

Comment: I'm not sure the HttpOnly flag is a good idea even in a browser, but I agree; it seems bizarre to respect the flag in non-browser HTTP clients.

Comment: I agree with 6265 in situations where not all content on the page is under your control. For example, sites like Facebook, if a JavaScript got loose it could hijack your session and do naughty stuff, but you still need to be logged in to Facebook to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

This is now listed as a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T1pyAAC).